# Unable to get ChannelRead0 fired

Tags: c#, netty

I'm new to DotNetty and I'm trying to receive a simple request (in binary format) from a socket

The class I've to deserialize is

```
public class PKKeepAlive
{
    public uint PacketType => 12003;
}
```

and the handler I tried to use is

```
    public class KeepAliveResponseHandler : SimpleChannelInboundHandler<PKKeepAlive>
{
    public override void ChannelRead(IChannelHandlerContext ctx, object msg)
    {
        var obj = msg as IByteBuffer;

        base.ChannelRead(ctx, msg);
    }

    public override void ExceptionCaught(IChannelHandlerContext context, Exception exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + exception);
        context.CloseAsync();
    }

    protected override void ChannelRead0(IChannelHandlerContext ctx, PKKeepAlive packet)
    {
        string message = packet.ToString();

        Console.WriteLine($"Quote of the Moment: {message.Substring(6)}");
        ctx.CloseAsync();
    }
}
```

This is registered inside a WPF sample application and performs

```
private async void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        var group = new MultithreadEventLoopGroup();

        var bootstrap = new Bootstrap();
        bootstrap
            .Group(group)
            .Channel<TcpSocketChannel>()
            .Option(ChannelOption.TcpNodelay, true)
            .Handler(new ActionChannelInitializer<ISocketChannel>(channel =>
            {
                //channel.Pipeline.AddLast("LoginResponse", new Temp());
                channel.Pipeline.AddLast("KeepAliveResponse", new KeepAliveResponseHandler());

            }));


        IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.116");

        IChannel bootstrapChannel = await bootstrap.ConnectAsync(new IPEndPoint(ip, 20000));


        var login = new LoginRequest { UserName = "if" };

        var bytes = login.Serialize();
        IByteBuffer buffer = Unpooled.WrappedBuffer(bytes);

        await bootstrapChannel.WriteAndFlushAsync(buffer);

    }
```

The problem I've is that I can have a breakpoint on the public override void ChannelRead(IChannelHandlerContext ctx, object msg) method and I see I've 8 bytes readable but it doesn't stop on protected override void ChannelRead0(IChannelHandlerContext ctx, PKKeepAlive packet) where I think I should have the package just deserialized

Consider in my real scenario I'll have to handle different packets based on the uint PacketType (actually in supersocket I read that value and perform a switch)

Any suggestion on this?
Thanks